# Inline block by statement (last line)

Tags: css

How do I to align the last line in left, keeping the first line alignment?

this code:

```
<ul style="position:inline-block; text-align:center; width:120px; background-color:green; margin:0; padding:0;">
        <img src="http://img2.timeinc.net/instyle/images/2011/GalxMonth/2012-Charlize-Theron-400.jpg" width="33px"> 
    <img src="http://img2.timeinc.net/instyle/images/2011/GalxMonth/2012-Charlize-Theron-400.jpg" width="33px"> 
       <img src="http://img2.timeinc.net/instyle/images/2011/GalxMonth/2012-Charlize-Theron-400.jpg" width="33px"> 
       <img src="http://img2.timeinc.net/instyle/images/2011/GalxMonth/2012-Charlize-Theron-400.jpg" width="33px"> 
       <img src="http://img2.timeinc.net/instyle/images/2011/GalxMonth/2012-Charlize-Theron-400.jpg" width="33px"> 

</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vinoli/59cLmvxo/

Comment: Fix your HTML `<li>` not `<il>` and similarly for the closing tags.

Comment: Ok, I removed <li> just  to simplify my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target the last item of the list, exemple :

html:

```
<ul class="myList">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul.myList li { background-color: #ff0000; }
ul.myList li:last-child { background-color: #00ff00; }
```

Just put the css you want for each case.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmnzxt1o/)

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your tag such as  to reference it directly in your styles.css then use the align left as you would normally.

Alternatively, you could just put in an inline style for just that item specifically instead of just your ul. Like this:

`<il style="position:inline-block; text-align:left; width:120px; background-color:green; padding:5px;">
       <img src="http://img2.timeinc.net/instyle/images/2011/GalxMonth/2012-Charlize-Theron-400.jpg" width="33px"> 
        </il>`

Answer (score 0):

It's li tag and not il and please don't use inline style instead of css file. You can dispose a line with centered images and a line with images align to the left like:

```css
ul {
    position:inline-block;
    width:120px;
    background-color:green;
    padding:5px;
    list-style: none;
}
.align-left: {
    text-align: left;
}
.align-center {
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    width: 33px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="align-center">
        <img src="http://img2.timeinc.net/instyle/images/2011/GalxMonth/2012-Charlize-Theron-400.jpg">
         <img src="http://img2.timeinc.net/instyle/images/2011/GalxMonth/2012-Charlize-Theron-400.jpg">
         <img src="http://img2.timeinc.net/instyle/images/2011/GalxMonth/2012-Charlize-Theron-400.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="align-left">
        <img src="http://img2.timeinc.net/instyle/images/2011/GalxMonth/2012-Charlize-Theron-400.jpg">
         <img src="http://img2.timeinc.net/instyle/images/2011/GalxMonth/2012-Charlize-Theron-400.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>
```